# Iinheritence returning different types

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I've been recently looking at making a table for a personal project I'm on with my journey learning C++. It needs to be able to have different datatypes in columns.
I tried a solution using maps previously and it was just too slow for large tables.

My question here is is this a good approach. Or if there is a better way to do what I'm doing. It seems a little off to me casting pointers when wanting to use the values.
The table class will essentially be a vector of these columns either the template or the inherited. I'm looking more to optimise the table in a way that adding columns (only types defined at compile time not new ones) is fast as opposed to adding a row.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

class BaseCol
{
public:
    virtual void GetValue(int index, void** pValue) = 0;

};


class DoubleCol : public BaseCol
{
public:
    void GetValue(int index, void** pValue) override
    {
        *pValue = &m_values.at(index);
    }

    void push_back(double val)
    {
        m_values.push_back(val);
    }

    void SetData(std::vector<double> data)
    {
        m_values = data;
    }

private:
    std::vector<double> m_values;
};
```

Edit: Usage example, a quick print that will print a value from a column:

```
void PrintValForCol(BaseCol* col)
{
    void* pd = nullptr;

    col->GetValue(1, &pd);
    double value = *static_cast<double*>(pd);

    if(typeid(*col)  == typeid(DoubleCol))
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
};

int main()
{
    DoubleCol t;
    std::vector<double> initData({ 9,2,3,4,5 });
    t.SetData(initData);

    PrintValForCol(&t);


    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Are the column datatypes fixed at compile time, or do they need to be determined at runtime?  If the latter, a "raw" template won't work - you'll need some form of type erasure.

Comment: At the moment the types are restricted at compile time. More columns can be added but no more types.
I was going to look at adding different types after compiling but thats a future concern - I'll take a note of type erasure for then.
My main question was for it the types were decided before compling.

Comment: you can have only elements of the same type in a vector. All instances that inherit from `BaseCol` can be refered to by a `BaseCol*`, but all instantiations of the template `TemplateBaseCol` are different unrelated types.

Comment: can you show how you want to use `BaseCol` / `TemplateBaseCol` ?

Comment: It'd be mainly just access fnctions to the data so in some code for the table class have `Table::GetCellValue( int row, int col)`  from a `std::vector<BaseCol>` stored in Table. If i was using such function its return type wouldn't be easy as BaseCol and all derived classes would store different values. 

After @463035818_is_not_a_number's comment I see yeah the template class wouldn't work.

I guess this is more question of a safe way of having different derived classes returning different types.

Comment: storing a `DoubleCol` in a `std::vector<BaseCol>` is object slicing.  A vector can only store elements of one type. A `std::vector<BaseCol>` can only hold elements of type `BaseCol` not eg `DoubleCol`, you need pointers (or references) for polymorphism. Please add a usage example in the question.

Comment: Apologies I did mean BaseCol* in my comment. Added a small quick usage. Basically just if I wanted funtions that could call a function on anything that inherits BaseCol but they might return different types.

Comment: What I personally would go with – if following this approach *at all*: Have a class `BaseCol` and let the *template* inherit from. Then have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseCol>> data;`. However you'd typically would want to iterate over the *rows* and thus would like to have the column data close together. A `std::vector<std::tuple< /* the types you need for a column*/ >> myTable;` appears preferrable to me, or even better a vector of your custom class `MyDataRow`!

Comment: Interesting, would there be many downsides or other approaches that would be typically preferred. I've honestly been wracking my brain thinking of other approaches.

Comment: The downside of the approach you are trying is that you separate the data from one row over different vectors with the result of, when iterating over the rows, hopping around in memory when evaluating one data row, as each vector stores its data in its own, separately allocated piece of memory. The only advantage I can think of is that you might dynamically add, replace or remove entire columns.

Comment: A single vector of tuples or your own structs doesn't give you this flexibility, but keeps all the data located close together in a continuous memory block, i.e. making iterations fast – even more because the data of a single row isn't scattered over this continuous memory either, but held together in one chunk of memory.

Comment: Ah so for row iterations the vector of tuples or struct give a much better result.
I am actually wanting to be able to add columns.

Comment: A vector of tuples/structs is statically typed – adding new columns is not foreseen in this design. A compromise then might be a vector of vectors where each inner vector represents a data *row*. The values within such a data row might be represented by `std::variants`. Faster iterating over rows as row data still is close together, but more complicated to manage, and more error prone. I'd thus try this approach only if you encounter performance problems with your current one.

Comment: About adding columns: We're speaking about *dynamically* adding columns, i.e. while the programme is running, do we? Be cause *statically* you always can just re-compile with additional types added to tuple/struct. Data persistently stored would need to be appropriately modified, too, of course.

Comment: btw you edited the question to remove the template and ask only about inheritance, but text is still asking "My question here is which approach is preferred between these two basic implementations.", Its not really clear what the question now is actually

Comment: I'll edit the question youre right!
Also yes dynammically adding more columns but of the types determined at compile time. So adding another double column!

Comment: Dynamically added columns are always doubles? If so, then we could operate on our struct again: `struct Row { uint32_t id; std::string name; StateEnum state; std::vector<double> additionalColumns; };` – just as an example...

Comment: Is there a meaningful *maximum* of columns, by the way? If you have a fix set of total columns your struct could simply always contain *all* data and you might just *not show* irrelevant data to the user...

Comment: There likely would be a meaningful max number of columns I haven't thought that far yet.
As for the adding columns I more used double as an example sorry - the new columns could be any of the predefined types so if i had int/string/double at compile time then a new column of those types could be added.
Much appreciate the suggestions and help thank you @Aconcagua